# Convertir xPath a cadena String

Tags: python, xpath

Tengo un código en Python, el cual descarga contenido html de una web por medio de un request, y despues con xpath extraigo el html que me interesa.

Mi duda es si puedo convertir el objeto html del xpath a una cadena String, es decir si cojo un div con xpath, que me de el div completo en string, por ejemplo:

```
<div><a></a href="#">infoiwrneg<a/div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente usa `extract()`

```
#me creo tu ejemplo
import parsel

path = '<div><a></a href="#">infoiwrneg<a/div>'
parse = parsel.Selector(text=path)

#No tengo un string, tengo un objeto Selector xpath
IN[14]: parse
Out[14]: <Selector xpath=None data='<html><body><div><a></a>infoiwrneg<a>...'>

#Extaemos todo en forma de string
In[15]: parse.extract()
Out[15]: '<html><body><div><a></a>infoiwrneg<a></a></div></body></html>'
```